# Getting Inexistent-account After Installation of ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

When installing ejabberd, I get the following error when I log into the web client:

> 19:58:12.684 [warning] Access of <<"admin@xxx.co">> from <<"::ffff:111.111.111.111">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>

The log file shows the account being created after installation, but I guess when I start ejabberd it overwrites the log. I am logging in with admin@xxx.co and the correct password. Is there a way for we to inspect the Mnesia database to see what account are installed?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for we to inspect the Mnesia database to see what
>   account are installed?

There are several ways.

This works with all database configurations, if you can use the 'ejabberd' shell script:

```
$ ejabberdctl registered_users localhost
user1
user2
```

Alternatively, if you use the default internal Mnesia database:

```
$ ejabberdctl dump_table /tmp/accounts.txt passwd
$ cat /tmp/accounts.txt 
{tables,[{passwd,[{record_name,passwd},{attributes,[us,password]}]}]}.
{passwd,{<<"user1">>,<<"localhost">>},<<"mypass11">>}.
{passwd,{<<"user2">>,<<"localhost">>},<<"mypass22">>}.
```